# Not able to run RichFaces, getting different kind of exceptions

Tags: maven, jsf, richfaces

I have developed a sample JSF application and it is running fine but I am having hardtime to run RichFaces example in JSF.

**My runtime environment details: Weblogic 12.1.2, JEE 6 and JSF 2.0.**

I downloaded below JARs and placed then in my `WEB-INF/lib` but it doesn't work.

- richfaces-4.5.0.Final.jar
- richfaces-a4j-4.5.0.Final.jar
- richfaces-core-4.5.0.Final.jar

With these JARs, when I started my server I got class not found exception related to AtmosphereServlet so I included `atmosphere-runtime-1.0.2.jar` JAR and then I was getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.reflections.scanners.AbstractScanner` exception.

`org.reflections.scanners.AbstractScanner` was not from a very popular JAR and only JAR I found for this was [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/r/Downloadreflections096jbosserrair2jar.htm). Even though I was not convinced that I should use this but still to try out I added this and then I was getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.CometProcessor`.

To resolve this I added [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcatalinacometjar.htm) JAR. Now, I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.servlet.http.HttpEventServlet` exception.

I am totally convinced that I am not heading in right direction because like this I may end up adding Tomcat and Jboss/Wildfly JARs in my classpath.

I searched blogs there is no clear post saying that with these JARs RichFaces works, whatever JARs were mentioned in the post I added all, at this moment I have following JARs but still have the same exception:

- atmosphere-runtime-1.0.2.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- guava-19.0.jar
- richfaces-4.5.0.Final.jar
- richfaces-core-4.5.0.Final.jar
- catalina-comet.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.jar
- cssparser-0.9.18.jar
- reflections-0.9.6_jboss_errai_r2.jar
- richfaces-a4j-4.5.0.Final.jar
- sac-1.3.jar

Another problem I am facing is that I don't know Maven so I am not able to resolve the dependencies using it, I tried below pom.xml but nothing works, it doesn't download any JAR, it simply builds some almost useless JAR.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.jvi.weblogic.jms</groupId>
  <artifactId>jms-producer</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>jms-producer</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
    <!--version>4.2.2.Final</version-->
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
    <!--version>4.2.2.Final</version-->
  </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**Could someone please guide and help me to run RichFaces in my JSF application.**

P.S.: I am able to run PrimeFaces but RichFaces dependencies looks very bad.

---

**UPDATE 1:** I also followed the official documentation and downloaded the distribution from [here](http://richfaces.jboss.org/download/stable) and had below mentioned JARs but still no help.

- cssparser-0.9.18.jar
- guava-19.0.jar
- richfaces-a4j-4.5.17.Final.jar
- richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final.jar
- richfaces-page-fragments-4.5.17.Final.jar
- richfaces-rich-4.5.17.Final.jar sac-1.3.jar

Comment: Richfaces has and end-of-life for almost two years now. Don't start developing anything new based on it! https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesEnd-Of-LifeQuestionsAnswers

Comment: @Kukeltje Ok, thank you for the note. I will have to convince my managers, a counter argument which may come is that we are not using a some complex feature of RichFaces so it is not likely that we will run into a RichFaces bug.

Comment: maybe not but a newer version of jsf might also become problematic.

Comment: If you need to use Atmosphere there is `richfaces-push-depchain`. I don't know what you'd need AbstractScanner for but at the very least you should be able to Google the primary jar.

Comment: @Makhiel All those JAR were included because of class not found exceptions thrown by WL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had got it working. Below are the RichFaces JARs which would work with JEE 6 container and JSF 2.0; **this is tested and RichFaces works with these JARs in `WEB-INF/lib`**

- [richfaces-components-api-4.0.0.Final.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.richfaces.ui/richfaces-components-api/4.0.0.Final)
- [richfaces-core-api-4.0.0.Final.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.richfaces.core/richfaces-core-api/4.0.0.Final)
- [richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.richfaces.ui/richfaces-components-ui/4.0.0.Final)
- [richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0.Final.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.richfaces.core/richfaces-core-impl/4.0.0.Final)
- [cssparser-0.9.18.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.cssparser/cssparser/0.9.18)
- [sac-1.3.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.w3c.css/sac/1.3)

Last 2 JARs are the dependencies.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call it working when you downgrade to an even older version.

Comment: I am not covering all possible versions and scenarios here, so I have specifically mentioned that the version details

Comment: Richfaces last and final version is/was 4.5.17.Final, and it was released on Jun 2016, almost 6 years ago. Giving up on trying to updating from 4.5 to 4.0... what would you want me to call that?